# My php/mysql register form doesnt work write. What do i do?

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: This was answered. Use the comment for help.

So i'm making my own social network named Dabox! and have programmed a registration form. i tested it out by putting username, password and email.

I put my username as test, my password at test and email as test@dabox.xyz. i tested it and it had came out as:

INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test@dabox.xyz')
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'.

My code was:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "daboxdb";
$user = ($_POST['user']);
$pass = ($_POST['pass']);
$mail = ($_POST['email']);
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
    VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$mail')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

I don't know what the problem is. Can you help me?

Comment: You're not going live with that actual code I hope.

Comment: im using a different code now that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your **ID** column which is going to act as **primary key**. You try to insert **duplicate** data